# Remove Points / Lines Canvas Python Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, canvas, pyqt5

i use the following Code to draw lines in matplotlib with mouse Event. Every click they save the coordinates and draw lines.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

class LineBuilder:
def __init__(self, line):
    self.line = line
    self.xs = list(line.get_xdata())
    self.ys = list(line.get_ydata())
    self.cid = line.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self)
def __call__(self, event):
    if event.inaxes!=self.line.axes: return
    self.xs.append(event.xdata)
    self.ys.append(event.ydata)
    self.line.set_data(self.xs, self.ys)
    self.line.figure.canvas.draw_idle()
    print(self.xs)
    print(self.ys)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_title('click to build line segments')
line, = ax.plot([0], [0], marker="o", linestyle="") 
linebuilder = LineBuilder(line)
plt.show()
```

Is it possible to delete same lines? For example if my Point 2 are not on the right position, then i would like delete the complete lines and points.

How can I do this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're building an interaction that's more complex than simply creating a point where the user clicked, I suggest that you use a button.

You need to define exactly what action you want to implement: remove the last point, remove all the points, remove all the points but the ones that were used for initialization...

I'm gonna show you how you can create a `Reset` button that will remove all the points, based upon [this example](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/widgets/buttons.html) from Matplotlib's doc.

First, create an `Axes` object that your button will fill.
You'll want to adjust the main ax so the two don't overlap.

```
from matplotlib.widgets import Button

plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
breset_ax = plt.axes([0.7, 0.05, 0.1, 0.075])
breset = Button(breset_ax, 'Reset')
```

Then you'll set the button's callback.
I find it relevant to define that callback in the `LineBuilder` class, as it will clear the encapsulated points.

```
class LineBuilder:
    ...

    def reset(self, _event):
        self.xs = []
        self.ys = []
        self.line.set_data(self.xs, self.ys)
        self.line.figure.canvas.draw_idle()
```

Then, bind that callback to the button:

```
breset.on_clicked(linebuilder.reset)
```

This will give you something like that:

[image]

And clicking on the `Reset` button will remove all the points that have been drawn.

---

Complete code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Button

class LineBuilder:
    def __init__(self, line):
        self.line = line
        self.xs = list(line.get_xdata())
        self.ys = list(line.get_ydata())
        self.cid = line.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self)

    def __call__(self, event):
        if event.inaxes!=self.line.axes:
            return
        self.xs.append(event.xdata)
        self.ys.append(event.ydata)
        self.line.set_data(self.xs, self.ys)
        self.line.figure.canvas.draw_idle()
        print(self.xs)
        print(self.ys)

    def reset(self, _event):
        self.xs = []
        self.ys = []
        self.line.set_data(self.xs, self.ys)
        self.line.figure.canvas.draw_idle()

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_title('click to build line segments')
line, = ax.plot([0], [0], marker="o", linestyle="")
linebuilder = LineBuilder(line)

plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
breset_ax = plt.axes([0.7, 0.05, 0.1, 0.075])
breset = Button(breset_ax, 'Reset')
breset.on_clicked(linebuilder.reset)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you write a function to use key_press_event to delete a picked point?
So, the user will pick a point with the mouse and deleted with "delete button"

somthing like this:

```
def on_key(event):
    if event.key == u'delete':
        ax = plt.gca()
        if ax.picked_object:
            ax.picked_object.remove()
            ax.picked_object = None
            ax.figure.canvas.draw()
```